# Optimizing SELECT through indexes

Tags: sql, informix, indexing

I have a large table of about 7M rows (and counting). I'm trying to optimize a SELECT to be as fast as possible. SELECT is from a single table, no joins. Database is IBM Informix. SELECT speed is priority, however there is a pretty constant number of inserts to the table.

There are 23 parameters in WHERE, but I've identified the dates and the language as the ones that are worth indexing:

```
...
WHERE (? >= valid_from OR valid_from IS NULL)
AND (? <= valid_to OR valid_to IS NULL)
AND ((? >= date_from AND ? <= date_to) OR (? >= date_from AND ? <= date_to)) 
AND language = ?
...
```

Now, what would be the best way to create indexes on that?

1. Do I create separate indexes from valid_from, valid_to, date_from, date_to and language? Or do I create three composite indexes (valid_from, valid_to), (date_from, date_to) and language? Or do I create one large composite index with all five? All fields are mandatory.
2. Are indexes on dates that are being compared a good idea, or should I restrict myself only to those fields that use = (exact match)?
3. If the composite indexes are the way, I guess the order of the fields in composite index is important - how do I order columns in index? Columns date_from and date_to would give me the biggest first reduction, but language might give me the faster reduction (though this is assumption I pulled out of thin air - see question 2).
4. If there are multiple indexes, does Informix use all of them or just one (and which one)?
5. My tests show that order of conditions in WHERE is not important, however I might be wrong - is it?
6. Some of the conditions in WHERE are on columns which are sets. Informix doesn't allow me to index those columns. Does that mean that those conditions are matched by sequential scan? Does it make sense speed-wise to move those to separate table and JOIN them?

What I've done so far:

- Obviously, there are no joins and this is a denormalized table. I'm paying for this with a somewhat larger number of rows that are being inserted, which is fine with me since updates are not time sensitive.
- I'm using pretty large Informix extents to avoid fragmentation, and pagesize which gives the best results for my table.

Comment: When such a large number of fields are being searched, a table scan is often faster than running a half-dozen index scans, each of which may take a significant fraction of the time required to do a table scan.

Comment: Jon, is it also the case when the table itself is pretty big? It's in the 5GB range at the moment.

Comment: @Domchi: That is definitely part of the problem.  There are a couple of approaches that may help: normalization will probably reduce the size and may speed things up; partitioning based on date, or a frequently-used high-cardinality field (maybe your `language` field), will effectively handle one filter "for free".  7M is not a lot of rows, but it sounds like you have a very wide table; schema?  I'm not familiar with Informix so I'm not the best person to address this.

Comment: Jon, yes; one row can be up to 8K. If I normalize it and put all conditions in smaller table, and bigger fields in another table, will the database be smart enough not to sequentially scan both tables? As of now, sequential scan takes ages (measured in minutes if not tens of minutes).

Comment: @Domchi: It may scan each of the smaller tables, but if it then has all the key values it needs to find the target records in the main table it can use a bitmap index (at least, MS SQL will, dunno bout Informix).  This is the gist of the data warehousing technique of "fact tables" and "dimensions."  This approach depends on being able to strip down your main table to just keys and a handful of attributes; can you post the schema for your table?  A simplified outline should be fine.

Comment: Jon - to put it simply, table has two large LVARCHAR(4300) columns and several NVARCHAR(255) which take the gist of the space. I could move them to another table, but then I'll probably have 1:1 JOIN. Normalized, the data spans through at least 5-6 main tables. If 1:1 JOIN doesn't defeat the purpose, this is something I could definitely try - but first I'll take my chances with different combinations of indexes, they look like lower hanging fruit.

Comment: @Domchi: Ouch.  I would definitely move at least the two large fields out of the main table, unless Informix stores `LVARCHAR`s separately, like other databases typically handle BLOBs.  While you'll have to join to get that data, the DB won't have to skim past all those GB of data while it does the table scan.  You'll only read what you need.

Comment: @Domchi: It would help if you could provide us with the table schema and indexes you've created!.. Are there any rows that you know can be excluded from this table to obtain the desired results? (I'm trying to shrink the table size).. creating a clustered index to physically order the datafile in sync with the index files would also dramatically speed up the query!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Informix either; you will have to test. Postgres is smart enough to combine separate index scans on the variables separately in the obvious way if it wants to, and it estimates (not always so well) whether that approach is better than the table scan. However, I suspect that the composite 5-column index will work well here.

I have another suggestion: use a default to set NULL values of dates to infinite extremes; then you don't have to special case NULL. Furthermore, that probably captures the business logic correctly.

If the two ? represent the same parameter you can slightly simplify `(? >= date_from AND ? <= date_to)` with `? IS BETWEEN date_from and date_to`. Just syntactic sugar, won't affect query plans.

Answer (score 1):

Your and/or logic is likely to make any optimizer very unhappy about trying to create a useful index.

However you can create functional indexes in Informix, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0712wilcox/index.html.  So for this approach you'd create user defined functions such that you can write:

```
...
WHERE ? >= null_small_date(valid_from)
  AND ? <= null_large_date(valid_to)
  AND language = ?
  // hack, hack.  These 4 values should be the same as, but in a different order from
  // the next line .  This sanity check will let the index skip many possible records.
  AND max_date(?, ?) >= date_from AND min_date(?, ?) <= date_to
  AND ((? >= date_from AND ? <= date_to) OR (? >= date_from AND ? <= date_to)) 
  ...
```

With this in mind you could then create a single concatenated index on `(null_small_date(valid_from), null_large_date(valid_to), language, date_from, date_to)` which would let you skip most of your results to only focus in on a small fraction of your table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm yet one more person who doesn't know Informix, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark.  Depending on how selective the various columns are, you might be able to index only one or two of them to achieve the performance you want.

Updating Stats is something worth validating.  It also looks like Informix supports query hints:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/0502fan/0502fan.html

which would allow you to specify exactly which index you want to use.